# Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python

Trying to setup client Python script in my Windows system and finally i got stuck up with the below error, Tried in the Google and myself of about 4 hrs. But not able find out the solution. Since i am very new to the Python, I could not able to find out the solution.

Please have a look at below code and its error, So you may have solution for me,

Error:

```
C:\Python26>python C:\xampp\htdocs\cequel-dev\mbtools\main_inject.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\cequel-dev\mbtools\main_inject.py", line 12, in <module>
    import injectdir
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\cequel-dev\mbtools\injectdir\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import action
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\cequel-dev\mbtools\injectdir\action\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from command import list
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\cequel-dev\mbtools\injectdir\action\command.py", line 28, in <module>
    action_list[action.name]=action
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Code:  (Line no: 19 to 28)

```
try:
   action_list={}
   for file in filenames:
      if file.endswith('.py') and file != '__init__.py' and file != 'command.py':
         #Import the file as a module action_imp
         exec "import {0} as action_imp".format(file[0:-3])
         #Get the action object from action_imp. Name is a required method for all actions
         action=action_imp
         #Put the file name in file_name
         action.file_name=file[0:-3]
         action_list[action.name]=action 
except:
```

This seems like a array attribute error. So i have tried with if condition, But no luck so far.

So i have stuck with the last line ( "action_list[action.name]=action" ). Please let me know if you have any suggestions or any quick solution to suppress the error in the for loop.

Thanks.

Comment: try `hasattr: (module object, name)`.

Comment: what is `action_imp`

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay what syntax is that?

Comment: Hey. What is `action.name`? The error says that your module has no variable `name`, so it is rather a problem with that module than with this code. P. S. Maybe you are looking for `action.__name__`? It will give you module's name (like filename).

Comment: @Victor  - Actually i do not know what will be the value for action_imp and action.name respectively. But i have tried to print the variable "file" and i got something like "<type 'file'>".

Comment: @Yadheendran, so I guess it is not your own code, right? Btw, try to put `print dir(action)` after `action=action_imp` and see what happens. It should print all functions/variables that this module contains. Might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment after the exec statement says, every action has to have a name.

Ensure that every file listed in `filenames` (except `__init__.py` and `command.py`) contains a variable `name`.

Alternatively, you can suppress the error by replacing line 28 with:

```
try:
    action_list[action.name]=action
except AttributeError:
    print "Could not register action", action.file_name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. The error got suppressed and it is working fine now. :)